# Найти слова между скобок, регулярные выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Для поиска слов между скобок я использую следующий код:

```
    final String str = "([word1]word2 {word3})";
    final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\(|\\[|\\{)(.*?)(\\)|\\]|\\})").matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
```

Суть в том, что у меня всё выражение обернуто круглыми скобками и по задумке оно всё должно выводится в результат, но вывод такой:

> [word1
>   word3

Не могу написать регулярное выражение, что бы оно выдавало всё что между самыми внешними скобками, а при их отсутствии, просто слова в скобках из строки(т.е. word1 и word3).
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: вы точно хотите сделать это одним выражением? просто это сильно запутает того, кто будет на это все смотреть через полгода-год (возможно это будете вы сами). почему не разбить это выражение на несколько?

Comment: IMHO, задача проще, наглядней, а главное - надёжней решается без регекспов. Во всяком случае в вашем варианте никак не учитываются непарные ситуации типа `[word}` в самом простом случае, не говоря уж о вложеных скобках.

Answer (score 2):

Вообщем сам решил свою проблему. Пришлось как и посоветовали разбить на два выражения. Сначала проверяю обернута ли строка внешними скобками, с помощью matches, если нет, тогда уже с помощью find ищу скобки в строке.
метод clearString у меня просто очищает от лишних пробелов и других символов

```
    public static List<String> getWords(final String str) {
    final List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\W(\\(|\\[|\\{)(.*?)(\\)|\\]|\\})\\W").matcher(str);
    if (m.matches()) {
        words.addAll(Arrays.asList(Brackets.clearString(m.group(0)).split(" ")));
    } else {
        m = Pattern.compile("(\\(|\\[|\\{)(.*?)(\\)|\\]|\\})").matcher(str);
        while (m.find()) {
            words.add(Brackets.clearString(m.group(0)));
        }
    }

    return words;
}
```